# mysql_fetch_array does not retrieve all rows

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table";
$result = mysql_query($query, $db);
$all = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
echo mysql_num_rows($result) . ":" . count($all);
```

This returns

```
2063:7
```

I have not used count before, so I'm not 100% sure it's not counting the table columns. It's late and I might be going nuts.

Here's another example of what's happening:

```
$result = mysql_query($query, $db);
echo "Rows: " . mysql_num_rows($result) . " <BR />";

$player_array = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($player_array);
echo "</pre>";
```

Which outputs:

```
Rows: 9 
Array
(
    [playerID] => 10000030
)
```

TL;DR: I submit queries which return multiple rows, but fetch_array only gives me a small portion of those rows in the resulting array.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`mysql_fetch_assoc` returns only one row in once you have to use loop to retrieve all rows

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
   print_r($row);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Every call to `mysql_fetch_assoc($result);` gives you **one row** of the result set:

*([from the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php))*

> mysql_fetch_assoc — Fetch a result row as an associative array
>
> Returns an associative array that corresponds to the fetched row and moves the internal data pointer ahead. `mysql_fetch_assoc`() is equivalent to calling `mysql_fetch_array`() with `MYSQL_ASSOC` for the optional second parameter. It only returns an associative array.

You have to use the function in a loop:

```
$all = array();

while(($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))) {
    $all[] = $row;
}
```

[The example in the document shows how it is done](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php).

Comment: My apologies for being a dunce. This is on the tail end of a huge debug and I haven't used PHP much in years. That's my story!

Comment: @sejje: No need to apologise :)

Answer (score 2):

mysql_fetch_assoc doesn't work that way, you need to call it multiple times to get all rows. Like this:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($db_result))
{
  print_r($row);
}
```