# How do I loop through MySQL query results? I've tried everything and it just won't work

Tags: php, sql, while-loop, iteration

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM owners";

            $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);


            $data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);


            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                echo $row['uuid'];
            }
```

This isn't working at all but if I do this

```
            $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);


            $data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);


            while($row = $data) {
                echo $row['uuid'];
            }
```

It just spams the screen with the text that is meant to be printed.

Comment: Check This question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5218088/mysql-fetch-array-does-not-retrieve-all-rows

Comment: If you only want the uuid, you really should change your query to only return the uuid.  (replace * with uuid)  As it is, the database is returning everything in the table, whether you're using it or not.

Comment: What is the expected output / result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be there is only one row try this

```
        $query = "SELECT * FROM owners";
        $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            print_r($row);
        }
```

Comment: How would I print more than one row? use the `mysqli_fetch_array()`?

Comment: What you get with above code ? Share one complete row

Comment: This will print more than one row.  In fact, it will print every row returned by the query.  That's because the statement `$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)` evaluates to true every time there's a new row to fetch, until there are no more rows to fetch.